# 'X' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx, tsx

I am rending two simple joke cards in TypeScript and the cards do show up in my browser but I also get this error:
**'Jokes' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key**

I am new to TypeScript and cannot figure out for the life of me what the problem is. I have tried adding `<></>` between the `<Jokes />` in my App.tsx file but that doesn't work. I can't figure it out and was hoping someone could guide me in fixing this.

`Jokes.tsx`

```
import { jokeList, JokesPunchlines } from './jokeList';
import './App.css';

function Jokes() {
    return (
        jokeList.map((joking: JokesPunchlines) => {
            return (
                <div className="box">
                    <strong>{joking.setup}</strong>
                    <br />
                    <p>{joking.punchline}</p>
                </div>
            );
        })
    );
}

export default Jokes;
```

`Joke List`

```
export interface JokesPunchlines {
    id: number,
    setup: string,
    punchline: string,
}

export const jokeList: JokesPunchlines[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        setup: "What's the best thing about a Boolean?",
        punchline: "Even if you're wrong, you're only off by a bit"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        setup: "Why do programmers wear glasses?",
        punchline: "Because they need to C#"
    }
];
```

`App.tsx`

```
import './App.css';
import Jokes from './Jokes';

function App() {
  return (
    <Jokes />
  );
}

export default App;
```

`index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have tried adding `<></>` between the `<Jokes />` in my `App.tsx` file but that doesn't work. I can't figure it out and was hoping someone could guide me in fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the error says, an array of React components isn't a React component itself. While it'll still work in the JavaScript, TypeScript doesn't like it. You can rectify it by adding a JSX fragment around the returned array, and interpolate the array into the fragment. You can also leave off the `: JokesPunchlines` since `jokeList` is typed properly (and maybe call the mapping argument, a joke object, `joke` or `jokeObj` or something - `joking` isn't a great variable name).

```
function Jokes() {
    return (
        <>
            {
                jokeList.map((joke) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="box">
                            <strong>{joke.setup}</strong>
                            <br />
                            <p>{joke.punchline}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I genuinely thought about doing that exact same thing but it seemed wrong in my newbie mind. I apologize for the time you spent helping me. I should have tried this before asking. But thank you so much either way. I have learned something now.

Answer (score 0):

By using implicite return typescript has some difficultie.

You can type function Jokes with return type. Its will help.

also this should do the job.

```
import { jokeList, JokesPunchlines } from './jokeList';
import './App.css';

function Jokes() {
    return <>{
        jokeList.map((joking: JokesPunchlines) => {
            return (
                <div className="box">
                    <strong>{joking.setup}</strong>
                    <br />
                    <p>{joking.punchline}</p>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }</>;
}

export default Jokes;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I genuinely thought about doing that exact same thing but it seemed wrong in my newbie mind. I apologize for the time you spent helping me. I should have tried this before asking. But thank you so much either way. I have learned something now.